# How to implement hotlinking prevention in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, hotlinking

My application is on GAE and I'm trying to figure out how to prevent hotlinking of images dynamically served (e.g. /image?id=E23432E) in Python. Please advise.

Answer (score 11):

In Google webapp framework, you can extract the referer from the [Request class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html):

```
def get(self):
    referer = self.request.headers.get("Referer")
    # Will be None if no referer given in header.
```

Note that's `referer`, not `referrer` (see [this dictionary entry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/referer)).