# Prevent hot linking for get_serving_url() in Google App Engine

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

Is there a way to prevent hot linking for images that are served by the Images Service method get_serving_url()?

I only found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/903144/734765) but I don't think it would apply to get_serving_url().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - If you want any kind of access control for images you're serving from Blobstore/Google Storage then you should write a BlobstoreDownloadHandler and use send_blob to return the image after doing whatever access control you would like.

If you're using the crop or resize options of get_serving_url() then you would need to do this transformation yourself and store the result in blobstore, which is what you would then return.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do referrer checks on blobstore or image service URLs.