# Google App Engine: traffic source

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to identify where traffic to a Google App Engine website is coming from? e.g. the previous website that the user was on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [How to implement hotlinking prevention in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903144/how-to-implement-hotlinking-prevention-in-google-app-engine)

```
def get(self):
    referer = self.request.headers.get("Referer")
    # Will be None if no referer given in header.
```

And I've just tried this in the [console](http://con.appspot.com/console/):

```
import os
os.environ['HTTP_REFERER']
```

And it returned

```
'http://con.appspot.com/console/'
```

Check if it's there first before using however.